# In Solaris how do you startup a script automatically without user input?

Tags: linux, boot, solaris, su

I'm using Oracle Solaris, and i would like to startup a script automatically everytime i turn on my computer and log into the desktop, however the script i want to run requires elevated permission, so i have to use SU to run the script.

is there anyway to do this without user input?

Answer (score 0):

Install [sudo](http://www.gratisoft.us/sudo/) and configure it to allow you to run this one particular script without a password.

Answer (score 0):

Use [RBAC](http://www.cuddletech.com/blog/pivot/entry.php?id=362) which is part of Solaris unlike sudo which is only included starting from Solaris 11.
It allows you to run a script as root without providing a password. Solaris provides fine grain privileges so only granting the one(s) really needed by your script would be more secure.

Answer (score 0):

By noting "Oracle Solaris," I'm assuming you're using v11 or v10.

Easiest way is to add your startup script into the run levels.  ie:  install script in /etc/init.d and hardlink to something in /etc/rc3.d.

And if you're using v10 or v11, you could use SMF instead of the runlevels.